# Restricting feature generation to a particular entity in FeatureTools

Tags: featuretools

I'm trying to understand how to specify `primitive_options` in FeatureTools (version 0.16) to include only a certain entity. Based on the [docs](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.dfs.html) I should be using `include_entities`:

> List of entities to be included when creating features for the primitive(s). All other entities will be ignored (list[str]).

### Simple case

Here's some example code:

```
import pprint
from featuretools.primitives import GreaterThanScalar

esd1 = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)

def run_dfs(esd, primitive_options={}):
    feature_defs = ft.dfs(
        entityset=esd,
        target_entity="customers",
        agg_primitives=["count"],
        where_primitives=["count",GreaterThanScalar(value=0)],
        trans_primitives=[GreaterThanScalar(value=0)],
        primitive_options=primitive_options,
        max_depth=4,
        features_only=True
    )
    pprint.pprint(feature_defs)

run_dfs(esd1)
```

This produces:

```
[<Feature: zip_code>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions) > 0>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions) > 0>]
```

Suppose I'm interested in the sessions and transactions counts and whether sessions where larger than 0. Based on the docs I'd go for `include_entities` here:

```
run_dfs(esd1, primitive_options={
          "greater_than_scalar":{
              "include_entities":['sessions']}
        })
```

The output from this, however, is:

```
[<Feature: zip_code>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions)>]
```

Both GreaterThanScalar features are gone now. If I use `ignore_entities` instead I get:

```
run_dfs(esd1, primitive_options={
            "greater_than_scalar":{
                "ignore_entities":["transactions"],
            }
        })

[<Feature: zip_code>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions) > 0>]
```

So it works, but I'm not sure why `ignore_entities` gives the result I need and `include_entities` does not. Am I missing something?

### More complex case

Although I sort of got the simple case to work, what I really want is something a bit more complicated. I'd like to to get a boolean feature that tells me whether there were more than zero sessions on a particular device.

Do do this:

```
esd2 = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)
esd2['sessions'].add_interesting_values()
run_dfs(esd2)
```

yielding:

```
[<Feature: zip_code>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = desktop)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = tablet)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = mobile)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions) > 0>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions) > 0>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = mobile)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = desktop)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = tablet)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = desktop) > 0>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = tablet) > 0>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = mobile) > 0>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = tablet) > 0>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = mobile) > 0>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = desktop) > 0>]
```

The features I need are 4 to 6 counting from the bottom. If I try to restrict `dfs` to limit itself to sessions entity and device variables:

```
run_dfs(esd2, primitive_options={
            "greater_than_scalar":{
                "ignore_entities":["transactions"],
                "include_variables":{"sessions":["device"]}
            }
        })
```

the result is:

```
[<Feature: zip_code>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = desktop)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = tablet)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = mobile)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = mobile)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = desktop)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = tablet)>]
```

No GreaterThanScalar features.

Is there a way to make `dfs` to give me just the three GreaterThanScalar features I want here?

### Update: Third case

Is there a way to limit what gets counted under `where`? For example:

```
esd3 = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_entityset=True)
esd3['sessions'].add_interesting_values()
esd3['products'].add_interesting_values()

run_dfs(esd3, primitive_options={
            "greater_than_scalar":{
                "ignore_entities":["transactions","sessions"],
            },
            "count":{
                "ignore_variables":{"transactions":['session_id']}
            }
        })
```

gives:

```
[<Feature: zip_code>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = desktop)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = tablet)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(sessions WHERE device = mobile)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = mobile)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE products.brand = B)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = tablet)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE products.brand = A)>,
 <Feature: COUNT(transactions WHERE sessions.device = desktop)>]
```

Is it possible to limit the `COUNT(transactions WHERE ...)` features to only `products`. I'd still want to keep the `COUNT sessions ...` features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding 'session_id' from the 'sessions' entity to the `include_variables` option will generate the features you're looking for:

```py
primitive_options={
    "greater_than_scalar":{
         "ignore_entities":["transactions"],
         "include_variables":{"sessions":["session_id", "device"]}}}
```

The `Count` primitive uses the entity index as its base, as well as any `where` columns. If you only include the `where` column for the `GreaterThanScalar` primitive options, `dfs` ends up ignoring all the `Count` features for `GreaterThanScalar` because they all use an implicitly ignored column (the entity index). In this case, the desired `Count` variables use the 'sessions' entity, so adding the 'sessions' entity index ('session_id') to the `included_variables` option allows for the desired features to be generated.

Also, in the first example using `include_entities`, the `GreaterThanScalar` features are lost because the 'customers' entity (the target entity) isn't included. The `Count` features are all aggregation features in the 'customers' entity; they represent the count of something per each customer. In order to use the `Count` features, the `GreaterThanScalar` primitive needs to be allowed to use both the 'customers' entity where the `Count` features are located as well as the entity that the desired `Count` feature is based on ('sessions' in this case).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, Frances! This is a bit more subtle than the documentation let's on. If I add `session_id` to `include_variables` I still get `<Feature: COUNT(sessions) > 0>` as a feature. Any way to exclude that?

Comment: I added a third case to the original question about limiting what gets included in `where` features.

Comment: Currently, there isn't a way to require specific variables be present so I don't believe there's an easy way to prune to `Feature: COUNT(sessions) > 0>` using `primitive_options`. However, `dfs` has the optional parameters `drop_contains` and `drop_exact` that might suit your needs.

Comment: Similarly for your third case, the logic is a bit too complicated. One thing you could try, however, is to use two separate instantiated `count` primitives each with a different set of options to limit what variables/entities they can/can't act on. For example, one could ignore the 'transactions' entity entirely while the other includes the 'transactions' entity along with whatever additional restrictions you want to place on the primitive.

Comment: Separate `count` primitives is a very interesting approach. I'll look into that. And thanks again for your help Frances. I realize that not all cases can or need to be handled via `primitive_options`. Filtering by `drop_...` or through postprocessing is also an option. Just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing anything.